# How to select records in one table but not another with multiple PKIDs?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here is my setup:

Table `records` contains multiple (more than two) PKID columns along with some other columns.

Table `cached_records` only has two columns, which are the same as two of the PKIDs for `records`.

For instance, let's assume `records` has PKIDs 'keyA', 'keyB', and 'keyC' and `cached_records` only has 'keyA' and 'keyB'.

I need to pull the rows from the `records` table where the appropriate PKIDs (so, 'keyA' and 'keyB') are not in the `cached_records` table.

IF I was working with only ONE PKID, I know how simple this task would be:

```
SELECT
    pkid
FROM
    records
WHERE
    pkid NOT IN (SELECT pkid FROM cached_records)
```

However, the fact that there is two PKIDs means I can't use a simple `NOT IN`.  This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT
    `keys`.`keyA` AS `keyA`,
    `keys`.`keyB` AS `keyB`
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            `keyA`,
            `keyB`
        FROM
            `records`
    ) AS `keys`
        LEFT JOIN
                `cached_records` AS `cached`
            ON
                    `keys`.`keyA` = `cached`.`keyA`
                AND
                    `keys`.`keyB` = `cached`.`keyB`
WHERE
    (
            `cached`.`keyA` IS NULL
        AND
            `cached`.`keyB` IS NULL
    )
```

(The `DISTINCT` is needed because since I am only grabbing two of the multiple PKIDs from the `records` table, there could be duplicates and I really don't need duplicates; 'keyC' is not being used and it helps determine uniqueness of the records).

This query above works just fine, however, as the `cached_records` table grows, the query takes longer and longer to process (we're talking minutes now, sometimes takes long enough that my code hangs and crashes).

So, I'm wondering what the most efficient way is to do this kind of operation (selecting rows from one table where the rows don't exist in another) with multiple PKIDS instead of just one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be quicker:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
    `records`.`keyA` AS `keyA`,
    `records`.`keyB` AS `keyB`
FROM
    `records`
        LEFT JOIN
                `cached_records` AS `cached`
            ON
                    `records`.`keyA` = `cached`.`keyA`
                AND
                    `records`.`keyB` = `cached`.`keyB`
WHERE
            `cached`.`keyA` IS NULL -- one is enough here
```

Notes:

- with the query as table, you lose a lot of performance. You can do the distinct in the outmost SELECT here.
- it is enough to check one of the two keys if they are null, as none can be null
- you should verify that the `keyA` and `keyB` columns are of the same type, and no conversion occurs (seen such in working live code...)
- You should have proper indexes on the tables. Minutes for this query is the sign of something awful going on... (Or an insane amount of data)

Comment: i implemented some of your suggestions, but this was the killer: they keys were different types!  (i thought i had fixed this, but in dumping and restoring different db dumps, i guess i ended up using one that didn't have this fixed...)  so, i was joining with one table having the pkids as integers and the other as varchars.

Comment: Why killer?  Couldn't e.g. `records.keyA = CAST(cached.keyA AS INTEGER)` solve this?

Comment: @TerjeD it is not even needed, MySQL does that for you. The problem was not that it was **not working**, but that it was **extraordinarily sloooooow**.

Comment: yes, i am dealing with a rather large db.  the 'records' table has about 2 million records (however, there was a bit more logic in the query that i did not show that reduces what i am really using/pulling to 120k rows).  so, trying to cast all the columns was a huge performance hit.